# Lightsail Instance Fails Every 20 to 40 days

Tags: 20.04, nginx, aws, wordpress

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 on a 1 GB RAM 1 VCPU 40GB SSD Lightsail instance.
It runs NGINX serving a single Wordpress instance.  The WP site is the web presence of our local Apple user group and gets very little traffic.

About once a month (plus or minus a few days) the Wordpress site goes away.

When that happens I'm unable to SSH into the Lightsail instance, neither through my SSH client (iTerm2) nor the AWS console.  It appears to connect, but the screen is blank and there is no login prompt.

Rebooting the instance from the AWS console has no effect on the issue.

If I stop and restart the Lightsail instance everything comes back, but the public IP address has changed which means I need to make changes to DNS.

Syslog doesn't show anything I can see as the problem.

Any suggestions as to what I should be looking for?

Comment: Sounds to me like an IP addressing problem.  Are you not using a static IP address?

Comment: From the look of the AWS “Support” forum, [this is a relatively common issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=269360&start=50&tstart=0). There are a few possible solutions mentioned in the thread, but none are silver bullets. It may be better to switch to a self-managed EC2 instance 

Comment: @Nmath... yes it static addressing withing the limits imposed by AWS.  Stopping and restarting the instance forces a new IP address.

Comment: Qmatingo...  I think your exactly right.   I had almost reached that conclusion myself. I have an EC2 instance that's been running flawlessly for about 18 months.   Now I just have to do a bit of web searching to see if there's an easy way to migrate from Lightsail to EC2.  Given the view count on the forum thread you show above it's clear that nobody at Amazon gives a flying-fig about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

@matigo has the best solution.  "Move it to EC2".   Lightsail appears to be totally unsupported.  I think, though, that I'll look at Linode and Digital Ocean VPS offerings first.  No point rewarding AWS for bad service.

Comment: I did move it to EC2 and the problem persisted.  I added some additional logging and and it turns out that somewhere in the only two things running on the instance (nginx and wordpress+some plugins) there's a memory leak.  When restarted it's using 64% of available memory and in a month it consumes the rest and crashes.  A cron job that reboots the system once a week in the wee small hours of Sunday morning cured the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a low capacity instance in respect of website traffic. Lightsail instance crashes when heavy load is put on the system out of its capacity.

You can simply **reboot the instance**. It won't change your Server IP.

For permanent solution, Check your website traffic and chose instance as per your requirement.

Otherwise you can switch to EC2 with ELB or Autoscaling (Depends on your usage)

Comment: When it crashes on Lightsail a simple reboot from the AWS Console won't work.  You have to stop the instance and restart it, which gives you a new address.  I switched to EC2 and the problem persisted ( see comment below for the real problem & solution ).